I am using parameters in Amazon Redshift, the query works in Data Prep but Dataset fails with Import Error
I am using parameters in Amazon Redshift, so that I can pass them directly from Dashboard. The query works in Data Prep but Dataset fails with Import Error.
The parameters:
DateFrom - Day - 2024-01-01
DateTo - Day - 2025-01-01
The query:
SELECT org_uid, COUNT(DISTINCT item_uid) as active_items 
FROM organizations_activity 
WHERE item_updated_at BETWEEN <<$DateFrom>> AND <<$DateTo>>
GROUP BY org_uid

Query works fine and shows results apply it with Auto-preview in Data Prep. But saving dataset fails:
Refresh error details

Error type: 0 Learn more

Error details: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$" Position: 411

I tried to replace <<$DateFrom>> and <<$DateTo>> construction with :DateFrom and :DateTo construction, but in this case I get syntax error already in Data Prep stage:
sourceErrorMessage: 
ERROR: syntax error at or near ":" Position: 63
sourceErrorState:   
42601
sourceException:    
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
sourceType: 
REDSHIFT


What is Data Prep? Is it DataPrep — Low code data preparation in Python? It seems that your code is passing the parameters to Redshift, which doesn't know how to handle them. Redshift does not accept parameter placeholders in SQL queries -- your code will need to substitute them for actual values before sending them to Redshift.

@JohnRotenstein No, it is executed directly in Amazon QuickSight. Just a simple example how to get to Data Prep: Datasets -> New Dataset -> Redshift -> Create Dataset -> User Custom SQL -> Edit/Preview Data -> Apply.
